# How to use a member of Class type in custom annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations

Im new to java custom annotations and trying to define a member of type MyClass in my custom java annotation.

I tried to define it as follows:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Validate {
    MyClass check() default MyClass.class;
}
```

I get error here: Invalid type 'MyClass' for annotation member.

Could anyone help to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a custom class easily as an annotation member unless such a class is an `enum`. So if `MyClass` is not an `enum`, then it cannot be used.

You can find more information in the [Java 17 Language Specification $9.6.1 Annotation Interface Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1).

> The return type of a method declared in the body of annotation interface must be one of the following, or a compile-time error occurs:
>
> A primitive type
>
> String
>
> Class or an invocation of Class (§4.5)
>
> An enum class type
>
> An annotation interface type
>
> An array type whose component type is one of the preceding types (§10.1).

Therefore `MyClass` can be used only if it is an `enum` or it's type as `Class<MyClass>`.